# Function of the ing-forms in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, ing, phrase-analysis

I'm having a hard time figuring out what the exact function of "fascinating" and "working" is in the following sentence:

"This song deals with the most important concerns **fascinating** people **working** at a factory."

Do they both introduce a ing-clause or do they function as adjective phrases or something else entirely?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both non-finite clauses modifying *concerns* and *people* respectively. These are interpreted similarly to relative clauses (CaGEL p1263-1265), approximately:

> ...the most important concerns **that fascinate** people **who work** at a factory

or, depending on the context, they could also be interpreted with a progressive aspect:

> ... the most important concerns **that are fascinating** people **who
>   are working** at a factory